# Custom field for product custom options - Magento 2.4

Tags: magento2, custom-options, store-view

We used the following method, to create a custom field for the product custom option section: https://devhooks.in/blog/magento2-how-to-add-custom-field-in-custom-option

This works fine, but we can not define the value for a store view specific.

How can we modify the code, to save different values for store views?

See our; CustomOptions\Plugin\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier

```
<?php 
namespace Module\CustomOptions\Plugin\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier;

class CustomOptions
{

    public function afterModifyMeta(
        \Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\CustomOptions $subject,
        $meta
    ) {
        $meta['custom_options']['children']['options']['children']['record']['children']['container_option']['children']['container_common']['children']['custom_text'] =
        $this->getTitleFieldConfig(
            200,
            [
                'arguments' => [
                    'data' => [
                        'config' => [
                            'label' => __('Description'),
                            'componentType' => \Magento\Ui\Component\Form\Field::NAME,
                            'formElement' => \Magento\Ui\Component\Form\Element\Textarea::NAME,
                            'valueUpdate' => 'input',
                            'imports' => [
                                'optionId' => '${ $.provider }:${ $.parentScope }.option_id'
                            ]
                        ],
                    ],
                ],
            ]
        );
        return $meta;
    }

    /**
     * Get config for "Title" fields
     *
     * @param int $sortOrder
     * @param array $options
     * @return array
     */
    protected function getTitleFieldConfig($sortOrder, array $options = [])
    {
        return array_replace_recursive(
            [
                'arguments' => [
                    'data' => [
                        'config' => [
                            'label' => __('Description'),
                            'componentType' => \Magento\Ui\Component\Form\Field::NAME,
                            'formElement' => \Magento\Ui\Component\Form\Element\Textarea::NAME,
                            'dataScope' => 'description',
                            'dataType' => \Magento\Ui\Component\Form\Element\DataType\Text::NAME,
                            'sortOrder' => $sortOrder,
                            'validation' => [
                                'required-entry' => false
                            ],
                        ],
                    ],
                ],
            ],
            $options
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: I believe custom option doesn't allow store view scope.

Answer (score 0):

You can use event `catalog_product_save_after` to to save different values for store views like you want.

It's should look like this:

In etc/adminhtml/events.xml:

```
<event name="catalog_product_save_after">
    <observer name="change_value_for_special_store" instance="Module\Custom\Observer\ChangeValueSpecialStore" />
</event>
```

In class ChangeValueSpecialStore:

```
<?php

namespace Module\Custom\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;

class ChangeValueSpecialStore implements ObserverInterface {

    protected $storeManager;
    public function __construct
    (
        StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
    )
    {
        $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
    }

    public function execute(Observer $observer)
    {
        $product = $observer->getEvent()->getProduct();
        $stores = $this->storeManager->getStores(true); // get all stores id for loop
        foreach ($stores as $store) {
            if ($store->getId() == 1) {
                $yourValueHere = 'test 1';
                $product->setCustomText($yourValueHere); // example your custom field name is custom_text
                $product->setStoreId($store->getId());
                $product->save();
            }
            if ($store->getId() == 2) {
                $yourValueHere = 'test 2';
                $product->setCustomText($yourValueHere); // example your custom field name is custom_text
                $product->setStoreId($store->getId());
                $product->save();
            }
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! But how should we implement this?

Comment: @JGeer, I have update answer, you can check again

Comment: Thanks again! But can you tell me how to implement this well, in the module mentioned?